# Reactjs keypress regex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using ReactJS, I am trying to set a keypress regex listener. My code is below.

```
formation: function() { 
  var f1c = document.getElementsByClassName('f1t').value;   
  var validator = new RegExp('^[0-9.]*$');
  var runner = validator.test(f1c);
  var bling = document.getElementById('f1p2');

  if (runner) {
    alert("Vegetables");
  } else {
    alert("Fruits");
  }
},
```

This is called from a separate function, like so.

```
something: function() {
  return (
    <input type="text" className="f1t" onKeyUp={this.formation}>something</p>
  );
}
```

The problem is that the keyup event only runs as it should if I remove the if arguments, meaning that the keyup does work. However, there must be something off with my logic.

The code as shown above keeps showing `Fruits` when it is only supposed to show `fruit` if the value of `f1c` is not a number.

Comment: try to `console.log(f1c)` in your handler, and see what happens

Comment: your first block isn't valid javascript…there's some syntax errors. Can you fix it? Your if/else won't work for one thing

Comment: Yeah my console.log returns `undefined.` So I changed `ElementsByClassName` to `ID` and it returns what it should.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection of elements --`document.getElementsByClassName('f1t')[0].value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user presses a key, and the event fires, the function will get a reference to the element and the key in the form of a [React synthetic event](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events).

```
formation: function(e) {
  var theKeyPressed = e.charCode; // this is normalized for you by React
  var theElementPressed = e.target;
  var theValueOfTheElement = e.target.value;
  // do your thing
},

something: function() {
  return (
    <input type="text" className="f1t" onKeyUp={this.formation}>something</p>
  );
}
```

FYI, `type="text"` is redundant nowadays, it's the default.

Answer (score 2):

It's not good to directly access the DOM in React. Take a look at the following link to see best practices for handling form updates:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp={this.formation}>something</p>

formation: function(event) {
  var f1c = event.target.value;
  ...

}
```